# How to find the number of working days in each week (England)

Tags: excel, calendar, dataset

In excel, I have a column which contains week ending dates from 09/04/2023 to 30/03/2025.

I have data on the number of observations each week and I want to compare this to a baseline level from 2019/2020 (i.e. before Covid). Therefore, to make it a fair comparison, I need to compare not the weekly observations, but the weekly observations divided by the number of working days that week.

Is anyone aware of a pre-existing table of the number of working days per week (past and future) for England?

I've had a google and could do this manually but will be much quicker if I can just copy and paste from an existing table!

Comment: Is that Monday to Friday? Or for the hospitality industry where Saturday and Sundays are valid working days? What about public holidays? Have you looked at some of the functions like networkdays.intl() ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have te specific dataset which you are looking for, but there are websites such as: https://publicholidays.co.uk/
Which list UK bank hollidays and School hollidays.

What I would do was find a similar website specific to the hollidays you want to include. Then I would add them to a tabel, which you can then check against when calculating the number of working days i each week.